# Use String to find my.resources

Tags: vb.net

I have a number of resources called

```
My.Resources.diceDark1
My.Resources.diceDark2
My.Resources.diceDark3...
```

I want to do something like

```
For i as integer = 1 to 10
    button1.backgroundimage = My.Resources.diceDark i
Next
```

So it will cycle through all the resources and change the background image to that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Designer creates property getters and setters for the images etc you add to `Resources`.  So, for an image named `dicedark1.jpg`, it creates:

```
Friend ReadOnly Property diceDark1() As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Get
        Dim obj As Object = ResourceManager.GetObject("diceDark1", resourceCulture)
        Return CType(obj,System.Drawing.Bitmap)
    End Get
End Property
```

You can see these in `Resources.Designer.vb`.  So the resource "names" you use are not something like variables, but Property names for the `Resources` object.  But what you *can* do, is what you see in the getter, which is use `GetObject`:

```
Private DiceNames As String() = {"diceDark1", "diceDark2", "diceDark3" ...}
...
' assuming you have control refs in an array also:
For i As Int32 = 0 To 6
    picBox(i).BackgroundImage = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(DiceNames(i)) 
Next i
```

The property wrappers obviously make it easier to get at your resources.  To use the loop, you'll need the target controls in an array or list since `picBox + 1` or any variation thereof wont work any better than the `My.Resources.DiceDark i` reference.